# Using jQuery :contains selector

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have a div with id `kGrowl` and inside that div I have another div that has a select element with name = `mover`. I try to use this selector:

```
$('#kGrowl:contains([name=mover])').length
```

But it is currently returning 0. How is my selector wrong?

Thanks.

Edit:

Gabriel's answer is best but I also realized its the `:has` attribute that will take a jQuery selector, not contains. So you *could* do:

```
$('#kGrowl:has([name=mover])').length
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

contains is mostly for text content where a valid selector doesn't work. So if you wanted to do it the way you are showing it would be:

$('#kGrowl:contains("name=mover")').length but really you want the number of select elements named mover you would use:

```
$("#kGrowl div select[name='mover']").length
```

cheers.

Comment: Also I just realized its `:has` that takes an actual jQuery selector. Lol.

Comment: @Alex word... I was trying to remember which one it was also.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with `:contains`, but perhaps you should try:

```
$('#kGrowl *[name=mover]').length
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#kGrowl[name=mover]');
```

Edit: for elements with name=mover inside kGrowl:

```
$('#kGrowl div[name=mover]'); //note the space
```

Also check this page for more information on selectors http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#kGrowl:contains('[name=mover]')").length
```